# How to make cells fit Collection View

Tags: ios, swift, collectionview

I custom collection view cell by cell' size.

In case I have 1 or 2 cell, it works perfectly, but when I have 3 cells, it doesn't work well.

Here is my code in case I have 3 cells:

```
case 3:
let lastPhoto = info.albumOtherPhoto.photos.first
let lastPhotoWidth = lastPhoto?.width
let lastPhotoHeight = lastPhoto?.height
var sizeForFistPhoto : CGSize!
var sizeForOtherPhotos: CGSize!
if lastPhotoWidth > lastPhotoHeight {
    sizeForFistPhoto = CGSizeMake(screenWidth, screenWidth * 0.5)
    sizeForOtherPhotos = CGSizeMake(screenWidth * 0.5, screenWidth * 0.5)
} else {
    sizeForFistPhoto = CGSizeMake(screenWidth * 0.5, screenWidth)
    sizeForOtherPhotos = CGSizeMake(screenWidth * 0.5, screenWidth * 0.5)
}
self.sizes.append(sizeForFistPhoto)
self.sizes.append(sizeForOtherPhotos)
self.sizes.append(sizeForOtherPhotos)
```

and CollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return self.sizes[indexPath.row]
}
```

The result of my code is:

[image]

But I want it showing like this:

[image]

Is it possible to achieve this in code like I did (because I can achieve this in interface builder)?

Comment: Are you planning to have more cells or just 3? If so, you should subclass you layout class

Comment: More cells, maximum is 6, I've just test 1,2,3 cells :).

Comment: How do you expect it to behave with more cells?

Comment: I will set for 6 cases. If I have 7 cells, it will show like case I have 6 cells.

Comment: If you have 6 cells, then how do you want them to be displayed?

Comment: If I have 6 cells, then 6 images will have the same size in a square frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by changing the **Collection View Flow Layout** in interface builder from `vertical` to `horizontal`

[image]